# How to use texture packer with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am making a canvas game and I want to use one spritesheet with a json file. I have seen this used in pixi.js applications however I want to sue it in a plain js app. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about creating a spritesheet, then don't bother reinventing that wheel...there are dozens of sprite packers online. Here's the first one on Google: https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker

If you are talking about reading sprites off a spritesheet then you can:

- Create an in-memory image object using `var mySpritesheet=new Image(); ...`
- Use the clipping version of `context.drawImage` to clip the desired sprite from mySpritesheet and draw it on the game canvas as needed.

For example:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var sCols=5;
var sRows=2;
var sWidth=206/sCols;
var sHeight=111/sRows;

var spritesheet=document.createElement('canvas');
var sctx=spritesheet.getContext('2d');

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/avatars1.jpg";
function start(){
  spritesheet.width=img.width;
  spritesheet.height=img.height;
  sctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  for(var y=0;y<sRows;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<sCols;x++){
      ctx.drawImage(spritesheet,
                    x*sWidth,y*sHeight,sWidth,sHeight,
                    Math.random()*cw,Math.random()*ch,sWidth,sHeight
                   );
    }}

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

But to keep it simpler...

You don't really need the in-memory canvas as in my example. I use a canvas just in case you need to recolor a sprite or annotate a sprite.

It's much simpler to load your spritesheet into an image object and then use the clipping form of `drawImage` to clip each sprite from the spritesheet image and draw it onto your game canvas.

Here's another example using a simple spritesheet image rather than an in-memory canvas:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var sCols=5;
var sRows=2;
var sWidth=206/sCols;
var sHeight=111/sRows;

var spritesheet=document.createElement('canvas');
var sctx=spritesheet.getContext('2d');

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/avatars1.jpg";
function start(){  
  for(var y=0;y<sRows;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<sCols;x++){
      ctx.drawImage(img,
                    x*sWidth,y*sHeight,sWidth,sHeight,
                    Math.random()*cw,Math.random()*ch,sWidth,sHeight
                   );
    }}

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the in memory canvas or offer some reading material please?

Comment: Sure, but if you find the in-memory canvas confusing, then you can just as easily create an in-memory image object instead. I've added to my answer explaining why an in-memory canvas is more flexible than a spritesheet image.